# SwiftUI Scrollview Breaks NavigationLink Behavior

Tags: navigation, scrollview, swiftui, navigationlink

I'm having a problem where I toggle a setting in a details view, and immediately after the toggle of the setting, the navigation pops back to the main screen. This only happens when using a ScrollView instead of a List on the main screen. Does anyone have a solution or know if this is bug that will be fixed? I waited for Xcode 11 Beta 7 today, but that has not fixed the issue.

**Current Behavior With ScrollView:**

1. Click on a row to be taken to details screen
2. Click on the start to toggle the favorite setting
3. Immediately jumps back to the main screen

**Expected Behavior With ScrollView (Current Behavior With List):**

1. Click on a row to be taken to details screen
2. Click on the start to toggle the favorite setting
3. Stay on the details screen and be able to toggle the favorite setting over and over
4. Click on the back button to be taken back to the main screen

   ```
   import SwiftUI
   import Combine

   struct Sport: Identifiable{
       var id = UUID()
       var name : String
       var isFavorite = false
       var school : String
   }

   final class UserData: ObservableObject  {
       @Published var sportsData =
           [
               Sport(name: "soccer", isFavorite: false, school: "WPI"),
               Sport(name: "tennis", isFavorite: true, school: "WPI"),
               Sport(name: "swimming", isFavorite: true, school: "WPI"),
               Sport(name: "running", isFavorite: true, school: "RIT"),
       ]
   }

   struct ContentView: View {
       @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

       var body: some View {
           NavigationView{
               List{
                   ForEach(userData.sportsData){ sport in
                       if sport.isFavorite{
                           NavigationLink(destination:
                               DetailsView(sport: sport)
                           ){
                               HStack {
                                   Text(sport.name)
                                   Spacer()
                                   Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                                       .foregroundColor(sport.isFavorite ? .yellow : .gray)
                               }
                           }

                       }

                   }
               }
           }.navigationBarTitle("Settings")
       }
   }

   struct DetailsView: View {
       @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
       var sport: Sport
       var sportIndex: Int {
           userData.sportsData.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == sport.id })!
       }

       var body: some View {
           ZStack {
               Text(sport.name).offset(x: 0, y: 100)
               Button(action: {
                   self.userData.sportsData[self.sportIndex].isFavorite.toggle()
                   print(self.sport.isFavorite)
               }) {
                   Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                       .foregroundColor(self.userData.sportsData[self.sportIndex].isFavorite ? .yellow : .gray)
               }
           }.padding(.horizontal)
       }
   }



   #if DEBUG
   struct Testing_Previews: PreviewProvider {
       static var previews: some View {
           ContentView()
               .environmentObject(UserData())
       }
   }
   #endif
   ```

Comment: That's a weird bug and I couldn't come up with a workaround yet. Totally unrelated: it seems you are using `.navigationBarTitle()` on the wrong view. It should modify the content view of the `NavigationView`, not the `NavigationView` itself. In your case (`List`or `ScrollView`). This way you can give a different name to each pushed views separately.

Comment: Hi, I am experiencing exactly the same issue in my project. Were you able to find a workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It looks like a limitation of SwiftUI at the moment. Hopefully it’ll be fixed this summer after WWDC.

Comment: I am also having this issue...really annoying.

Comment: I seem to still be having this, or a very similar issue, in XCode 12. Are you still experiencing this?

Comment: This seems to be working as expected. I’m currently running Xcode 12.0 and iOS 14.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one thing that could be affecting this is it looks like you are destroying the original NavigationLink in the forEach if `favorite == false`.

So if that is the NavigationLink we came in on to the Detail, then it's disappearing when favorite is set to false. Is that what you are intending to do?